# Why might my service not be started and what can I do about it

Tags: android, android-service

On a particular (low-end) Android phone (running Android 5.1) one of my app's services will fail to start, when this happens logcat has the following lines:

```
D/nzy     ( 1499): shouldBlock from:<package name>, ComponentInfo{<service name>}elapsed:21270
D/nzy     ( 1499): ===ignore ==ComponentInfo{<service name>}
D/zlg     ( 1499): startService ===ignore ==ComponentInfo{<service name>}
```

I'm not clear as to the exact circumstances when the service fails to start. Although it does seem to be consistent that when I install the app from fresh the service is started, but if I then manually do a "Force Stop" of the the app and then restart it, the service will not be started, with the above output in logcat.

What do nzy and zlg refer to?

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: "I then manually do a "Force Stop" of the the app and then restart it, the service will not be started" -- how are you restarting it? Why are you using Force Stop, rather than terminating the process via Android Studio, `adb`, etc.?

Comment: I used "Force Stop" as this is something the user can do, so was interested in the impact (it also reproduced the problem). Having said that I experienced the problem before doing this manually. I'm not clear as to the exact circumstances it originally happened. The service is started on a clean install, but I did experience the problem after doing an "install -r". The app is restarted automatically (after a Forced Stop), not clear if this is because the app is set to run on boot, or because it has a sticky service.